# plotting graph using strings as x axis labels using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have a csv file with the following:

```
tau,date,value
003,24/15,90
006,24/18,80
009,24/21,85
012,25/00,90
015,25/03,95
018,25/06,75
021,25/09,90
024,25/12,95
```

Now I would like to make a line plot of the csv values in the file, and have on the x axis as labels the dates listed in the csv file.

Now I have the below program and when I tried to put the dates on the x axis as labels they did not appear.  How can I tweak this program to get the desired results:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys

data = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1], dtype='str',delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=(0,1,2))
x = data[:,0]
date = data[:,1]
y = data[:,2]
my_xticks = data[:,1]
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data columns you are reading in are stings, and because you specify `dtype='str'` in the call to `loadtxt`, your arrays `x`,`y` and `my_ticks` are as well. While matplotlib is happy to have strings provided in `plt.plot` it is not happy with strings in `plt.xticks`. So you need to convert the string array to float first, before passing it to `xticks`.

```
plt.xticks(x.astype(float), my_xticks)
```